# Pluralization bug: "You can accept an answer in 1 minutes"

Tags: bug, plurals

So I was going to accept an answer, and got this message:

[image]

I know this isn't important... But it should say 1 minute, not 1 minutes. This should be on the "unimportant" fixes, but it's so easy to fix, I figured that I may as well point it out.

Comment: What else should I use?

Comment: Again - What other required tag should I use? It's required to use discussion, bug, support or feature-request.

Comment: The tag isn't what's important. It's that pluralization "bugs" have been beaten to death.

Comment: So, what you're saying is... I shouldn't have made this?

Comment: No, just don't expect a whole lot to come of it.

Comment: Nah, it's fair enough, but unlikely to be fixed. The whole link to that particular tweet (or message about the tweet) has become somewhat of an inside joke.

Comment: Ok... I'm just going to nod my head and pretend like I understand you.

Comment: Well played good sir. Next time mumble something about Unicorns as well and include some freehand red circles. [Rep will be flying your way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta).

Comment: What....? Ok. Head nod. Understood.